# HTTP request in NodeJs - Need help in understanding the flow

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a new to nodejs/javascript and trying to find my way to accomplish what I want.

I want the program to wait for the https request before executing code from line 70 (second last line). How can I achieve this? Currently code execution continues  from line 71 onwards while the result of http request arrives later. I want to use the value of variable total in the code onwards.

Here's the code in text:

```
// Step 1 - Get total from firebase with the above details - Make a POST request to firebase
    var postData = querystring.stringify({
      order_id: orderUID,
      res_key: res_key
    })
    const options = {
      hostname: process.env.HOST,
      port: 443,
      timeout: 5000,
      path: process.env.CLOUD_GETTOTAL,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
      }
    }
    const request = https.request(options, resCFS => {
      resCFS.on('data', d => {
//        if (resCFS.status==200) {
          total = Number(d)
          console.log('Total: '+total) // I WANT VALUE OF THIS FIRST
//      }
      })
    })
    request.on('error', error => { //C4 Server error or Comms Error
      console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
      //res.sendStatus(500) // Send status to the app
      //return
    })
    request.write(postData)
    request.end() ///// LINE 70
    console.log('Total End: '+total) // THIS EXECUTES FIRST
```

Comment: Rather than a picture (which some can't read), please indicate which line is line 71 in the textual code.

Comment: You are trying to use `await` with functions that do NOT return a promise.  As such those `await` lines of code are useless.  In addition, you're using plain asynchronous callbacks and not process the result inside those callbacks.  You need to go back to the drawing board on how to write asynchronous code in nodejs and either follow the documentation or learn from literally thousands of such examples here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @jfriend00 What do you mean by not processing result inside callbacks? ...on('data'... is a callback and I am trying to get the value there? Something done wrong?

Comment: What is the point of this code?  You appear to attempt to get some `total` value and then you don't do anything with it.  Please show or describe what you are really trying to do.  And, YES your three lines at the end execute BEFORE the asynchronous callback does because that's how non-blocking, asynchronous operations in Javascript work.  If you want those to execute after you've gotten the result, then put those INSIDE the asynchronous callback, not at the end of your function.

Comment: FYI, this would be far, far easier to use a promise-based http request library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).  `https.request()` is pretty low-level and requires lots more code to handle everything properly.

Comment: @jfriend00 the rest of the code below this is not relevant to my question because I use the total to perform some calculations later, hence I have not pasted it above. Thanks for the suggestions. I will check them out.

Comment: It IS relevant because you can't use the total ANYWHERE else except in that callback.  That is part of your problem.  Inside that callback is the only place in your code where you know when the total is actually available and valid.

Comment: You should practise with some simple async code with callbacks, for example by using timeouts with callbacks, and putting console.log() at different places in the code. Then you will learn how async execution sequence works. In your code above, the execution path runs down the page first, before any of the async code, which is in the callbacks, gets executed. The whole point of the callback is that it is run later, when some async operation has finished and the result of the operation is ready to be processed. The code in line 71 is not async, it will run right after line 70.

Comment: And, by not showing the entire operation (like where you're trying to use the `total` value and what you're trying to accomplish here), we can't show a complete solution either.  It's 10x easier for us to show you how to solve your specific problem, than it is for us to teach all the possible generic concepts at work here.  But, we can't show you how to solve your specific problem, when you don't show the whole problem.  I could probably offer a complete solution in about 5 minutes if I could see the whole problem.